# What is the correct way to store complex data types in azure table storage with java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

I have been researching this for a while and I am not finding a clear answer to this. I want to use azure table storage instead of cosmosdb. The reason is that for my needs i only need key value lookup and table storage is a lot cheaper. However I want to store complex data in the table storage. That is each item I want to persist can have several other objects and a couple lists. I tried for hours to get this to work using azure documentation and googled blogs/tutorials. I eventually found info that seemed to conflict with itself some said it was possible, others said impossible. I feel like this shouldnt be a debate I also feel like you should be able to do it. Is there a best practice way to store complex data types in azure table storage? Or should i just use ObjectMapper and stringify the complex data i want persisted then persist it?

Comment: I haven't personally used it but it sounds like it should work based upon the documentation I saw. If you persist a JSON directly, then I am not sure if you would be able to query it directly but you can try it.

Comment: Yeah... One way I think would work but not sure if it is the best way which is why i ask this question. Persist the properties that are needed for querying in their respective columns, properties of the row, then persist everything else as a JSON string as its own column.... That would work. It just feels awkward, and im not sure if that is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you described in the comment is the correct approach. Azure Table Storage is a `Key/Value Pair` kind of storage and does not support storing JSON documents as is.

One approach would be to serialize the JSON document and store the entire document as string. Please note that in that case you will not be able to query on the JSON document attributes.

Other approach would be to flatten the JSON document and then store each attribute as key/value pair. For example, if your document looks something like:

```
{
  "firstName": "",
  "lastName": "",
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "zip": ""
  }
}
```

you can flatten it like following:

```
firstName: ""
lastName: ""
address_streetAddress: ""
address_city: ""
address_state: ""
address_zip: ""
```

and store that in your table.

Comment: ok cool thanks... As awkward as I find it, I think the objectmapper would be better than the above mentioned approached. I thought of that too but it seems even more awkward. It will also require a restructuring of the data anyway which objectmapper would just handle automatically. Thanks for your answer.